# DevExpress CustomJSProperties Get Row Values

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, devexpress

i am trying to get values of every field for mousemove tooltip (hint), so i need row values  but i only get key , please help me.

```
  gvSettings.CustomJSProperties = (s, e) =>
{
    MVCxGridView grid1 = s as MVCxGridView;
    int startIndex = grid1.VisibleStartIndex;
    int endIndex = grid1.VisibleStartIndex + grid1.SettingsPager.PageSize;
    var groups = grid1.GetGroupedColumns()
    .OrderBy(g => g.GroupIndex)
    .Select(g => g.FieldName)
    .ToArray();
    var clientData = new Dictionary<object, object>();
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        var key = grid1.GetRowValues(i, grid1.KeyFieldName);
        var groupValue = grid1.GetRowValues(i, groups);
        clientData.Add(key, groupValue);
    }
    e.Properties.Add("cpTooltipList", clientData);

};
```

Comment: If you debug/step into the code, does clientData contain what you expect?